# Android Spinner with "Radio Buttons" and Cancel button

Tags: android, spinner

I am looking for some guidance on how to develop the following spinner dialog shown below in the screen shot. It is present in your your android phone's Settings->Display-> Font Size option.

I have been able to implement a spinner with a simple CheckedTextView for each row.

But I am looking to develop something more specific as shown below.

I have searched all over the place for custom spinners.. but most of the show me how to add images etc to each item in the dropdown.. but nothing specific like this... where I have to "pre select" an item based on what is already chosen.

Some questions I am grappling with are....

1) Are those simple radio buttons beside a text view?

2) How would I know which item to "set selected" when I open the spinner dialog? Because my code would reside in my adapter, where my spinner would be in my Activity/Fragment.

3) How would I put a cancal button in a spinner dialog which dismisses it?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: @KaranMer I dont think a popumenu would allow it to be like a dialog as shown..

Comment: @Nitesh Mudireddy you can set that by using a spinnerdropdown +(Listview+Radiobutton+CancelButtonbutton) on Different LinearLayout:- where as you can set your cancel button click listener or you can set sellection on item

Comment: What you can do is open a **dialog** which have a **listview** in that you can use radio button with text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had created a custom DialogFragment and inside onCreateDialog i am creating AlertDialog and showing it.

use these as reference links

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs65/lecture13/lecture13.html